# Example request: cofibrations need not induce cofibrations of adjunction spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, fibration

The very first exercise in May and Ponto's *More Concise Algebraic Topology* asks for a demonstration of the following claim: given a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @<<< X @>i>> Z\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
Y' @<<< X' @>i'>> Z'
\end{CD}
$$
of spaces in which the vertical maps are cofibrations and $i$ and $i'$ closed inclusions, it is *not* the case that the induced map
$$Y \cup_X Z \longrightarrow Y' \cup_{X'} Z'$$
need also be a cofibration. They claim in fact there is an example in which $i'$ is an equality.
**What is such an example**?

While I'm at it, the second, dual question asks for a demonstration that given
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>>> X @<<< Z\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
Y' @>>> X' @<<< Z',
\end{CD}
$$
where the vertical maps are now fibrations, it need *not* be true the induced map
$$Y \times_X Z \longrightarrow Y' \times_{X'} Z'$$
is a fibration. Again, **why**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

Let $X$ be a nonempty CW complex.  Consider the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
X & \leftarrow & \emptyset & \rightarrow & X \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
X & \leftarrow & X & \rightarrow & X
\end{array}
$$
where all the arrows $X \to X$ are the identity.  The map of pushouts is the fold map $X \sqcup X \to X$, which is not injective, so not a cofibration.

We can more or less dualize this to obtain the second counterexample.  Let $Y$ be a path-connected space with more than two points, and consider 
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
Y & \rightarrow & Y & \leftarrow & Y \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
Y & \rightarrow & * & \leftarrow & Y.
\end{array}
$$
Then the map of pullbacks is the diagonal map $Y \to Y \times Y$, which is not a fibration.